# React-native contents of KeyboardAvoidingView in parent Dialog

Tags: ios, react-native

I have `<Dialog>` with a child `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` that prompts input fields for users. when field is focused and keyboard is prompted; `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` contents gets shifted above keyboard properly but the  `<Dialog>` view stays put, which makes the contents of `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` shift outside view and becomes unreadable.

Snippet:

```js
<Dialog
         keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"always"}
         visible={true}
         animationType="fade"
         dialogStyle={[
           this.state.orientation === "portrait"
             ? { width: "85%" }
             : { width: "75%" },
           { minHeight: hp("30%"), borderRadius: 15 },
         ]}
         overlayStyle={{ alignItems: "center" }}
         onTouchOutside={() => {}}
       >
           <KeyboardAvoidingView
             keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"always"}
             behavior="position"
             keyboardVerticalOffset={350}
           >
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
</Dialog>
```

Comment: i've faced same problem with dialogs/modals and ended up using `react-native-modalize` which is easy to use and saved me a lot of time

Comment: @VáclavRyska looking at the repo, `react-native-modalize` does not support pop-up dialogues. Am I missing something?